# Sql Query to get count from another row

Tags: mysql, telecommunication

```
MenuID  PreMenuID  Type
P2000   BS02        p
P8001   P2000       x
```

Hi Experts i have table structure given above which indicates menu id as main id and PremenuId Indicates the previous menu from which call is  transferred.

Now `type=x` means there is a exception in the call

from the above table `menuid=p8001` is transfer from `P2000` as shown in **premenuid**

**i want to get the count of exception generated in table but in mainId**

the output should be smthng like ths

```
MenuID  Exception  OnId
p2000     1        p8001
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please format your table schema, and show us a minimum sample data and expected result.

Comment: Can `P2000` be in multiple `MenuID`? Meaning, can another row exist like this ? `P8002 P2000 x`

Comment: @ashish jayara can you try my ans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your requirements right, a simple `group by`-Statement will do the job:

```
select PreMenuID as `MenuID`, count(Type) as `Exception`, MenuID as `OnID`
  where Type = x
  group by `MenuID`, `OnID`
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to join table with itself.

```
select a.MenuID, count(b.MenuID) as Exception, group_concat(b.MenuID) as OnID 
from tableName as a
join tableName as b on a.MenuID=b.MenuID
where a.type='x'
```

Comment: Don't you need to consider field `Type`? Something like `where Type='x'`...

Comment: Also I would use `join tableName as b on a.MenuID = b.MenuID` syntax rather than giving the join-condition in the where-clause. The `join ... on ...`-syntax has the advantage that you'll notice if the condition is missing, and won't execute a cross-join then.

Comment: @RenéHoffmann thanks for your remark, I was in hurry so I have made a mistake it

Comment: @krishn patel group_concat Not a suportng tag in my sql  m useing sql 2008